# hierarchical sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with this structure:

```
Id ParentId CountItems
```

I can calc levels for items by script:

```
 ;WITH cteSort AS
  (
  SELECT Id AS Child, ParentId AS Parent, 1  AS [Level]
    FROM [Catalog].[Category] WHERE Id = 0 
  union ALL
  SELECT Id AS Child, ParentId AS Parent, [Level] + 1 AS [Level]
  FROM [Catalog].[Category] 
       INNER JOIN cteSort ON [Category].ParentId = cteSort.Child and Id <>0)
```

I want rise from the lower level to the top and put to the current CountItems the sum of the fields CountItems children of standing on the lower level and current CountItems.
Like this:
Before

```
Id ParentId count 
0     0      0 
1     0      1 
2     0      1 
3     1      1 
4     1      1 
5     2      1 
6     3      1 
7     4      1 
8     4      1
```

After

```
Id ParentId count
0    0        8 
1    0        6 
2    0        2  
3    1        2 
4    1        3 
5    2        1 
6    3        1 
7    4        1 
8    4        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with trees in relational presentation recently, so i tried to resolve your problem but after some retries I get the following output: `GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression` when write following

```
WITH sum_cte AS
(
    SELECT
       Id, ParentId, [Count]
    FROM Category c

    -- find Categories that have no child
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Category WHERE ParentId = c.Id)

    UNION ALL


    SELECT
        s.ParentId
        -- find parent of current parent
        , c.ParentId
        , SUM(s.[Count])
    FROM 
        sum_cte s  
        JOIN Category c 
        ON s.ParentId = c.Id
    WHERE s.Id<>0
    GROUP BY s.ParentId, c.ParentId
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sum_cte ORDER BY Id
```

and I consider that it's impossible to resolve the problem with CTE. So I write a recursive function that gives the total count of all children.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSumOfChildren](@CategoryId INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sum int;
    SELECT 
        -- get sum of all children
        @sum = SUM(dbo.GetSumOfChildren(Id))
    FROM
        Category
    WHERE ParentId = @CategoryId AND ParentId <> Id

    SELECT 
        -- plus self count
        @sum = ISNULL(@sum,0) + [Count]
    FROM
        Category
    WHERE Id = @CategoryId

    RETURN @sum;
END
```

With this your task solves simple

```
SELECT Id,ParentId, dbo.GetSumOfChildren(Id) FROM Category
```

Answer (score 1):

my own solution with insert new field to table [level]:

```
;WITH cteSort AS
  (
  SELECT Id AS Child, ParentId  AS Parent,1  AS [Level]
    FROM table WHERE Id = 0 
  union ALL
  SELECT 
     Id AS Child,
     ParentId AS Parent,
     cteSort.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
  FROM table 
       INNER JOIN cteSort ON table.ParentId = cteSort.Child and table.Id<>0)

UPDATE table SET [Level] = (Select [Level] from cteSort where cteSort.Child = table.Id)

declare @max int
set @max = (select top(1) [Level] from table order by [Level]  Desc)
 while (@max >0)
 begin
     UPDATE t1
        SET t1.[count] = t1.[count] + t2.cnt ,
        from table as t1 
        cross apply (Select COALESCE(SUM([count]),0) cnt from table where ParentId =t1.Id) t2
        where t1.Id in (Select Id from table where [Level] =@max)
     Set @max = @max -1
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question leads more to a why?  Rather than an actual solution (having puzzled over this during my lunch) I do have some to contribute.

In pure programming terms you could accomplish this using a recursive function passing through the parent count and the node to process while maintaining an inner count for the current leaf.  Emulating this in pure SQL would be a more interesting endeavour as some of the programming techniques that would be used are far harder to implement (if there at all) in SQL.

My actual thinking had me not using som convulted sub-query per row (this is going to be expensive depending on the number of rows and would likely need a fixed number of levels) but translating the resultset into an XML object and then using XQuery to then obtain the number of descendants, then update your resultset with the results.  Unfortunately count() has no switch to count all descendants so you would have to revert to some subquery type logic to count on a row by row basis.  In addition, this approach seems to point towards having a fixed number of levels...

Which brings it back to the why?  If you passing this resultset over to a programming language like C#, Java, etc. for that to then process, it makes much more sense to implement the recursive calculation at that point and add that to the resultset prior to consumption.